# Why is my syntax not working to compute a new variable?

Tags: spss

I've been trying to compute a new variable that will tell me how many of the cases were not taking meds at all. (Value for Taking Meds--1=Yes, 2=No, 3=Unknown.)

I was able to run the syntax using OR but I can't run it using AND. But I need to know whether all of these equal the same number. When running using AND, I keep getting the error:

> Incorrect variable name: either the name is more than 64 characters,
>   or it is not defined by a previous command.

I've already double checked that everything is spelled correctly.

Thanks!

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet2.
COMPUTE NOT_Taking_meds_atentry2 = ANY (2, currentdepressionmed, currentanxietymed, currentadmed, currentpdmed, currentbipolarmed, currentmdmed,
currentadhdmed, currentcdmed, currentsimed, currentmhcothermed, currentdisruptdisANDdermed, currentfasmed, currentgenderdysmed,
currentintellectualdismed, currentimpulsdismed, currentpsychoticdismed, currentreactiveattachmed,  currentsleepprobmed, 
currenttraumaticdismed).
EXECUTE    .
```

Another version I tried:

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet2.
COMPUTE No_meds_atentry2 = (currentdepressionmed = 2) AND (currentanxietymed = 2) AND (currentadmed = 2) AND (currentpdmed = 2) 
AND (currentbipolarmed =2) AND (currentmdmed =2) AND (currentadhdmed=2) AND (currentdmed=2) AND (currentsimed=2) AND (currentmhcothermed=2) 
AND (currentdisruptdisANDdermed=2) AND (currentfasmed=2) AND (currentgenderdysmed=2) AND (currentintellectualdismed=2) AND (currentimpulsdismed=2) 
AND (currentpsychoticdismed=2) AND (currentreactiveattachmed=2) AND  (currentsleepprobmed=2) AND (currenttraumaticdismed=2).
EXECUTE.
```

And another one I tried:

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet2.
COMPUTE Taking_meds_atentry2=(currentdepressionmed =1 AND currentanxietymed= 1 AND currentadmed=1 AND currentpdmed=1 AND currentbipolarmed=1 AND currentmdmed =1
AND currentadhdmed=1 AND currentcdmed=1 AND currentsimed=1 AND currentmhcothermed=1 AND currentdisruptdisANDdermed=1 AND currentfasmed=1 AND currentgenderdysmed=1
AND currentintellectualdismed=1 AND currentimpulsdismed=1 AND currentpsychoticdismed=1 AND currentreactiveattachmed=1 AND  currentsleepprobmed=1 AND 
currenttraumaticdismed=1).
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: Usually the problematic variable name will appear just above the error message you posted

Comment: check the Log in the SPSS output; the blue-ish object in the output explorer

Comment: May I suggest using the COUNT command as an alternative?  Assuming all these columns are together in the data file, and there aren't any unwanted columns mixed in with them, number_of_meds_taken = COUNT currentdepressionmed to currenttraumaticdismed (1).

Comment: You could also try debugging your command by breaking it down to smaller groups - try just the first five variables, then the next five etc', then keep narrowing it down till you find the problem

Answer (score 0):

The best way to eliminate a true variable name error is to make SPSS do the work. In the top menu, select Utilities > Variables. In that dialog, select whichever variables you are using from the list and then click on "Paste." The variable names will be pasted into your syntax window. Move them around, put them into your COMPUTE statements. If you continue to get the error that a variable name is not spelled correctly, please let us know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That might be related to encoding.

Start with typing

```
*Encoding: UTF-8.
```

before the commands.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you accidentally type using a foreign language. At times the error persists even after deleting the specific character. You need to delete (not paste) and re-write

Answer (score 0):

I know its ages ago, but I just solved my own issue- I changed the variable measure to 'scale' instead of the 'unknown' default setting (: